# MIPS - Shifting register values by a numeric value

Tags: assembly, mips, byte-shifting

Can someone explain this to me? The problem is:

```
sll $t2, $t0, 44
```

and the goal is to find the value of $t2 after the operation. The initial values are:

```
$t2 = 0x12345678
$t0 = 0xAAAAAAAA
```

I understand that the pseudocode translation of "sll $t2, $t0, 44" is:

```
t2 = t0 << 44
```

and that the binary representation of t0 and t2 are:

```
t2 = 10010001101000101011001111000
t0 = 10101010101010101010101010101010
```

But how do you shift by 44 bits? I thought that there are only 32 bits for one value to begin with. How do I find the value of $t2 by shifting $t0 by 44 bits?

Comment: Where did you find that code? There are only 5 bits to encode the shift amount in an `SLL` instruction. So only shift amounts of 0..31 are possible. Unless your assembler handles that one as a pseudo-instruction and translates it into an `SLLV` (in which case only the low 5 bits of the shift amount register would be used anyway). With `DSLL32` on the MIPS64 architecture you could use a shift amount of 44 (the shift amount is still 5 bits, but offset by 32).

Comment: @Michael: This is from my textbook. I found it really confusing because of the 44. How would the SLLV work ("only the low 5 bits of the shift amount register would be used")?

Comment: See if the textbook mentions the 64-bit mode.

Comment: Probably a typo in the book.

Comment: If it isn't much trouble, could you tell me the name of the text book you are/were using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it is necessary to perform a shift by a ‘variable’ amount supplied through a third register:
sllv $s1,$s2,$s3 #s1 = s2 << s3
Implement the new sllv instruction using real MIPS instructions.

Note: shift amount must be between 0 and 31 (inclusive). So value in $s3 must be reduced modulo 32. This is easily done by ‘anding’ with 000…0011111 = 0x1F. This operation handles both cases when $s3 is positive or negative.

```
sllv $s1,$s2,$s3 # s1 = s2 << s3
add $s1, $s2, $0 # s1 <- s2
add $t0, $s3, $0 # t0 <- s3 (s3 must be preserved)
andi $t0, $t0, 0x1F # take mod 32
beq $t0, $0, EXIT # if t0 == 0, do nothing
addi $t1, $0, 0 # set i == 0 (start from 0)
LOOP:
sll $s1, $s1, 1
addi $t1, $t1, 1 # i=i+1
bne $t1, $t0, LOOP # LOOP while i is still not equal to t0
EXIT:
```

Here you go, this is the idea they mean in your text book, for a 32-bit machine, you need to take the modulo 32 of the shift (shifting by 36 can be explained like shifting by 4 if you think of it like a rotate) but what they mean is to take the modulo.

Comment: Thanks. This is something I'll think about.